# Italian bank will not freeze/close dead mother's account

Tags: bank-account, inheritance, italy

This is a brief overview of what happened, there are complicated details, this is just the highlights.

My mother-in-law died 4 years ago. She was an Italian citizen (born in the UK but lived in Italy for 45 years). Her UK account was frozen day one, however, her Italian account was not - it is still open today.

The bank would not freeze it as it was overdrawn, they continued to let Direct Debits come out of it, even her health insurance which they setup and would not cancel as they said "the policy owner needs to cancel it".  They took these moneys for 15 months and did not stop taking the direct debit until then.  We have since gotten that money back but not any interest on it.

We have no access to the account, the bank took over a year to send us documents we requested, they also failed to tell us for three years that they would not accept scans of documents and that they required the originals.

When my mother-in-law died she was €1275 over drawn with a savings account of €3000 that was invested for 1 year, when that matured at €3,300 (after interest and a few bills) she was €300 in credit.  She also had €1300 in shares...

Then a bill for inheritance tax for €1,900 came in, somehow they took that from her, I have no idea who signed this, I wonder if it is some family member but I know we did not!

This is much more complicated than I have put, however, the bank is still charging monthly fees on the account (€35 each month) and I want to know is there a way of putting this situation "in dispute". We are thinking we will pay it to stop further fees and then take action but I feel that would look as being "accepting of the debt" if we pay.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you, and where is the "there" that she lived in for 45 years?

Comment: Island of Elba, Italy.

Comment: So, you're also in Italy.  Is there a banking regulatory agency you can complain to?

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is.  If I understood correctly, the bank account is overdrawn, yet the bank still making payments & charging fees.  While I don't understand Italian law, it would seem that this is all the bank's problem, nothing to do with you.

Comment: @jamesqf It affect the estate. Either the estate now owns the account or the heirs do.

Comment: @mkennedy: But (at least in the US), heirs can not be required to pay the debts of the person they inherit from.

Comment: I am in the UK, she was (originally) from the UK too but moved to Italy many years ago.  In the UK, if someone dies their account is frozen (no more bills, maybe interest).  When she died we could get the funeral paid for by the Uk account which had to be ok'ed by the manager.  With this account they have continued charging, lent her money, let direct debits go out (inc her health insurance), withheld documents, and not communicated (failed to return calls).  The account has gone into credit a couple of times yet they continue to let it go overdrawn. I want to boycott the payment.

Comment: Where did the money come from to put it into credit?

Comment: Before she died the Bank suggested she invested some of her money in some kind of Savings Account for 12 months, when it matured it was sold (as we instructed) and the account went into credit.